# Defining buffer size when labeling text in QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, buffer

I need to set label buffer size to near zero but I dont want to overlap labels. How to define buffer size when labeling text?

Currently I am using labeling settings which is allowing all available text labeling showing in map. Text labeling are now fine for me, because there is both text classes, address numbers and street names. Unfortunately there is now also overlap labels.

[image: Current setting using overlapping labels]

[image: Using current settings in map]
[image: Using current settings in map (overlap labels)]

When I remove "Show all labels for this layer" -settings, overcrossing labels disappeared but also street name text although it should not touch address numbers.

[image]
[image]

How to set label buffering settings better if I want text classes very near together but no overlapping?